# Iphone: How to read return value of strftime SQLite function

Tags: iphone, sqlite, strftime

I need to read the column value of the following query

SELECT strtime('%Y-%m', created_at) as field FROM table GROUP BY field

the type of column field is 3 (I assume it is blog), but I need string

How should I?

Updated

> const char* sql = 
>   "SELECT CAST(strftime('%Y', created_at) as INTEGER) as year FROM table GROUP BY year
>
> if (SQLITE_OK == sqlite3_prepare_v2([AppDelegate db], sql, -1, &queryhandle, NULL)){
>     while(SQLITE_ROW == sqlite3_step(queryhandle)){
>
> ```
>    NSSTring* year  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",sqlite3_column_int(queryhandle, 0)];
> ```

this code gives me 3460 as year

(have checked cast as integer, and cast as varchar and sqlite3_column_text function)

Comment: I have solved it by creating seperating field for year, not elegant, but solution above didn't work in any variants

Answer (score 1):

As long as `created_at` has a time string format as specified in the [sqlite docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), it doesn't matter what storage type is used in a particular tuple (although you can find out using the `typeof`) function.  The result of the `strftime` function (you aliased it as `field`) is either text or null.

```
CREATE TABLE t (x BLOB);
INSERT INTO t VALUES ("2010-03-29\x0"), ("2010-03-28");
SELECT strftime("%Y-%m", x), typeof(strftime("%Y-%m", x)), typeof(x) FROM t;
|null|text
2010-03|text|text
```

Comment: have the same results in SQLite Manager, but can't get back valid data